# How to specify approved.txt files location for running approvals tests on TeamCity

Tags: c#, nunit, teamcity, approval-tests

I am trying to run my approvals tests from nUnit under TeamCity

```
    [assembly: FrontLoadedReporter(typeof(TeamCityReporter))]        

    [Test]
    [UseReporter(typeof(WinMergeReporter))]
    public void Test()
    {
    }
```

Unfortunately test fails because approvals is trying to pick up the approved file from C drive.

> Test(s) failed. ApprovalTests.Core.Exceptions.ApprovalMissingException :  Failed Approval: Approval File "C:\...approved.txt" Not Found.

Is there anyway I can specify right location for my approval files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is appeared that TeamCityReporter was hiding real reason of this issue.

Here is result of local run and output of approvals test with listed solutions.

> System.Exception :  Could Not Detect Test Framework
>
> Either: 1) Optimizer Inlined Test Methods
>
> Solutions: a) Add [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)] b) Set
>   Build->Opitmize Code to False     & Build->Advanced->DebugInfo to Full
>
> or 2) Approvals is not set up to use your test framework. It currently
>   supports [NUnit, MsTest, MbUnit, xUnit.net, xUnit.extensions,
>   Machine.Specifications (MSpec)]
>
> Solution: To add one use
>   ApprovalTests.Namers.StackTraceParsers.StackTraceParser.AddParser()
>   method to add implementation of
>   ApprovalTests.Namers.StackTraceParsers.IStackTraceParser with support
>   for your testing framework. To learn how to implement one see
>   http://blog.approvaltests.com/2012/01/creating-namers.html

It was tricky to catch because usually local run is done under Debug while deployment and tests under Release. Nevertheless I hope the question and answer will be helpful for somebody else.